# Minecraft bukkit plugin right click item

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a plugin for a server I am developer on and I was developing a plugin!
I wanted to do commands to spawn a boss egg in by doing `/boss give lvl <lvl> slime` after you did the command it would give you an item that you can right click to spawn the boss in! Well like all new developers stuff doesn't always go the way you think it does. Here's my code I put in for checking if a player right click air or a block with the item SLIME_BALL in the players hand.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerClicks(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    Action action = event.getAction();

     if (action.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) || action.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
         if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.SLIME_BALL) {
             player.sendMessage("You have right click a slime ball!");
         } 
     }

}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to be able to right click a item to spawn a slime in that size 32

Comment: And what's the problem you're having with your current code?

Comment: It wont allow me to right click the item to send the  player 'player.sendMessage("You have right click a slime ball!");' What I am trying to say is the code I have doesn't work and would like help debugging it to see what could be the issue for stopping the code from executing

Comment: Unfortunately, debugging help like that is usually off-topic for SO. Take a look in your code editor while the code is running and try to narrow down why it's not working. Check the variables are what you expect and you're not getting any errors.

Comment: I am not getting any errors that the weird thing It should work but it not working right strangely!

Comment: did you remember to register your event?

Comment: strangely as it sound but I don't really understand how events work with java. I know a bit of java to get around. But that beside the question

Comment: I think the playerListener is register

Comment: `I don't really understand how events work with java` probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are not seeing any stack traces in your logs, I would concur that your event listener is not registered. Let's say your listener class is called `MyEventHandler` it would be registered in `onEnable()` method, something similar to this

```
class MyPlugin extends JavaPlugin {
    ...
    public void onEnable() {
        Listener myEvtHnd = new MyEventHandler();
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents( myEvtHnd, this );
        ...
    }
}
```

In general, your handler looks appropriate. `PlayerInteractEvent` provides a convenience method `getItem()` that returns the player's current item-in-hand. However, regardless of which method is used, you *must* check that the `ItemStack` returned is not null, which will happen if the player has no item in-hand.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerClicks(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    Action action = event.getAction();
    ItemStack item = event.getItem();

     if ( action.equals( Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR ) || action.equals( Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK ) ) {
         if ( item != null && item.getType() == Material.SLIME_BALL ) {
             player.sendMessage( "You have right click a slime ball!" );
         } 
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of `action.equals()`, you can use `action ==`, as in:

```
if (action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
     if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.SLIME_BALL) {
         player.sendMessage("You have right click a slime ball!");
     } 
 }
```